# Border like classic window with dropshadow in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Does anybody know how to get a border like the following window in wpf?
I believe it is borderless and has drop shadow effect around the border.
I tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 <Border x:Name="myBorder" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" CornerRadius="0">
      <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect  ShadowDepth="2" Opacity="1" Direction="320" />
      </Border.Effect>
```

[image: Window eith classic Theme]

Comment: not any classes are here into 4.5.2 try to crate that by using your abilities :D

Comment: Sadly, this is non-trivial in WPF :P I've yet to find a simple solution for 3D effects like these.